# application with springboot closes connections to the database after 1 hour, how do I configure the connection time in a spring boot project?

Tags: postgresql, oracle, spring-boot, java-8, hikaricp

I have an application that queries a lot of data and then inserts it into specific tables. Due to the fact that there are many records, the application is taking a long time to complete. The funny thing is that the times it has been executed, it always ends after 1 hour showing SpringApplicationShutdownHook, this It causes not all the records to be processed and many need to be added.

I leave some screenshots of the log , please help.

[aplication starts at 16:08:14](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ek0Do.png)

[shutdown message on log at 17:08:13](https://i.stack.imgur.com/18gvq.png)

#Java8, #Springboot, #Postgree , #Oracle

I tried to review the configuration files, but I only found default hikari configuration with times but they are not 1 hour.

[aplication.properties]

```
logging.config=classpath:logback.xml
spring.config.location=D:/sise/dev/config.properties
postgre.jpa.show-sql=false
postgre.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
postgre.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
```

log of database connection is closing after 1 hour:

```
2023-01-09 17:08:13 [SpringApplicationShutdownHook] INFO  com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource - HikariPool-3 - Shutdown initiated...
2023-01-09 17:08:13 [SpringApplicationShutdownHook] INFO  com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource - HikariPool-3 - Shutdown completed.
2023-01-09 17:08:13 [SpringApplicationShutdownHook] INFO  com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource - HikariPool-2 - Shutdown initiated...
2023-01-09 17:08:13 [SpringApplicationShutdownHook] INFO  com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource - HikariPool-2 - Shutdown completed.
2023-01-09 17:08:13 [SpringApplicationShutdownHook] INFO  com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource - HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2023-01-09 17:08:13 [SpringApplicationShutdownHook] INFO  com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource - HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
```

[com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig]

```
/*
 * Copyright (C) 2013, 2014 Brett Wooldridge
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 * http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */

package com.zaxxer.hikari;

import com.codahale.metrics.health.HealthCheckRegistry;
import com.zaxxer.hikari.metrics.MetricsTrackerFactory;
import com.zaxxer.hikari.util.PropertyElf;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.naming.NamingException;
import javax.sql.DataSource;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.lang.reflect.Modifier;
import java.security.AccessControlException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.TreeSet;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadFactory;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;

import static com.zaxxer.hikari.util.UtilityElf.getNullIfEmpty;
import static com.zaxxer.hikari.util.UtilityElf.safeIsAssignableFrom;
import static java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit.MINUTES;
import static java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit.SECONDS;

@SuppressWarnings({"SameParameterValue"})
public class HikariConfig implements HikariConfigMXBean
{
   private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HikariConfig.class);

   private static final char[] ID_CHARACTERS = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".toCharArray();
   private static final long CONNECTION_TIMEOUT = SECONDS.toMillis(30);
   private static final long VALIDATION_TIMEOUT = SECONDS.toMillis(5);
   private static final long SOFT_TIMEOUT_FLOOR = Long.getLong("com.zaxxer.hikari.timeoutMs.floor", 250L);
   private static final long IDLE_TIMEOUT = MINUTES.toMillis(10);
   private static final long MAX_LIFETIME = MINUTES.toMillis(30);
   private static final long DEFAULT_KEEPALIVE_TIME = 0L;
   private static final int DEFAULT_POOL_SIZE = 10;

   private static boolean unitTest = false;

   // Properties changeable at runtime through the HikariConfigMXBean
   //
   private volatile String catalog;
   private volatile long connectionTimeout;
   private volatile long validationTimeout;
   private volatile long idleTimeout;
   private volatile long leakDetectionThreshold;
   private volatile long maxLifetime;
   private volatile int maxPoolSize;
   private volatile int minIdle;
   private volatile String username;
   private volatile String password;

   // Properties NOT changeable at runtime
   //
   private long initializationFailTimeout;
   private String connectionInitSql;
   private String connectionTestQuery;
   private String dataSourceClassName;
   private String dataSourceJndiName;
   private String driverClassName;
   private String exceptionOverrideClassName;
   private String jdbcUrl;
   private String poolName;
   private String schema;
   private String transactionIsolationName;
   private boolean isAutoCommit;
   private boolean isReadOnly;
   private boolean isIsolateInternalQueries;
   private boolean isRegisterMbeans;
   private boolean isAllowPoolSuspension;
   private DataSource dataSource;
   private Properties dataSourceProperties;
   private ThreadFactory threadFactory;
   private ScheduledExecutorService scheduledExecutor;
   private MetricsTrackerFactory metricsTrackerFactory;
   private Object metricRegistry;
   private Object healthCheckRegistry;
   private Properties healthCheckProperties;

   private long keepaliveTime;

   private volatile boolean sealed;

   /**
    * Default constructor
    */
   public HikariConfig()
   {
      dataSourceProperties = new Properties();
      healthCheckProperties = new Properties();

      minIdle = -1;
      maxPoolSize = -1;
      maxLifetime = MAX_LIFETIME;
      connectionTimeout = CONNECTION_TIMEOUT;
      validationTimeout = VALIDATION_TIMEOUT;
      idleTimeout = IDLE_TIMEOUT;
      initializationFailTimeout = 1;
      isAutoCommit = true;
      keepaliveTime = DEFAULT_KEEPALIVE_TIME;

      String systemProp = System.getProperty("hikaricp.configurationFile");
      if (systemProp != null) {
         loadProperties(systemProp);
      }
   }

   /**
    * Construct a HikariConfig from the specified properties object.
    *
    * @param properties the name of the property file
    */
   public HikariConfig(Properties properties)
   {
      this();
      PropertyElf.setTargetFromProperties(this, properties);
   }

   /**
    * Construct a HikariConfig from the specified property file name.  <code>propertyFileName</code>
    * will first be treated as a path in the file-system, and if that fails the
    * Class.getResourceAsStream(propertyFileName) will be tried.
    *
    * @param propertyFileName the name of the property file
    */
   public HikariConfig(String propertyFileName)
   {
      this();

      loadProperties(propertyFileName);
   }

   // ***********************************************************************
   //                       HikariConfigMXBean methods
   // ***********************************************************************

   /** {@inheritDoc} */
   @Override
   public String getCatalog()
   {
      return catalog;
   }

   /** {@inheritDoc} */
   @Override
   public void setCatalog(String catalog)
   {
      this.catalog = catalog;
   }


   /** {@inheritDoc} */
   @Override
   public long getConnectionTimeout()
   {
      return connectionTimeout;
   }

   /** {@inheritDoc} */
   @Override
   public void setConnectionTimeout(long connectionTimeoutMs)
   {
      if (connectionTimeoutMs == 0) {
         this.connectionTimeout = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
      }
      else if (connectionTimeoutMs < SOFT_TIMEOUT_FLOOR) {
         throw new IllegalArgumentException("connectionTimeout cannot be less than " + SOFT_TIMEOUT_FLOOR + "ms");
      }
      else {
         this.connectionTimeout = connectionTimeoutMs;
      }
   }

   /** {@inheritDoc} */
   @Override
   public long getIdleTimeout()
   {
      return idleTimeout;
   }

   /** {@inheritDoc} */
   @Override
   public void setIdleTimeout(long idleTimeoutMs)
   {
      if (idleTimeoutMs < 0) {
         throw new IllegalArgumentException("idleTimeout cannot be negative");
      }
      this.idleTimeout = idleTimeoutMs;
   }

   /** {@inheritDoc} */
   @Override
   public long getLeakDetectionThreshold()
   {
      return leakDetectionThreshold;
   }

   /** {@inheritDoc} */
   @Override
   public void setLeakDetectionThreshold(long leakDetectionThresholdMs)
   {
      this.leakDetectionThreshold = leakDetectionThresholdMs;
   }

   /** {@inheritDoc} */
   @Override
   public long getMaxLifetime()
   {
      return maxLifetime;
   }

   /** {@inheritDoc} */
   @Override
   public void setMaxLifetime(long maxLifetimeMs)
   {
      this.maxLifetime = maxLifetimeMs;
   }

   /** {@inheritDoc} */
   @Override
   public int getMaximumPoolSize()
   {
      return maxPoolSize;
   }

   /** {@inheritDoc} */
   @Override
   public void setMaximumPoolSize(int maxPoolSize)
   {
      if (maxPoolSize < 1) {
         throw new IllegalArgumentException("maxPoolSize cannot be less than 1");
      }
      this.maxPoolSize = maxPoolSize;
   }

   /** {@inheritDoc} */
   @Override
   public int getMinimumIdle()
   {
      return minIdle;
   }

   /** {@inheritDoc} */
   @Override
   public void setMinimumIdle(int minIdle)
   {
      if (minIdle < 0) {
         throw new IllegalArgumentException("minimumIdle cannot be negative");
      }
      this.minIdle = minIdle;
   }

   /**
    * Get the default password to use for DataSource.getConnection(username, password) calls.
    * @return the password
    */
   public String getPassword()
   {
      return password;
   }

   /**
    * Set the default password to use for DataSource.getConnection(username, password) calls.
    * @param password the password
    */
   @Override
   public void setPassword(String password)
   {
      this.password = password;
   }

   /**
    * Get the default username used for DataSource.getConnection(username, password) calls.
    *
    * @return the username
    */
   public String getUsername()
   {
      return username;
   }

   /**
    * Set the default username used for DataSource.getConnection(username, password) calls.
    *
    * @param username the username
    */
   @Override
   public void setUsername(String username)
   {
      this.username = username;
   }

   /** {@inheritDoc} */
   @Override
   public long getValidationTimeout()
   {
      return validationTimeout;
   }

   /** {@inheritDoc} */
   @Override
   public void setValidationTimeout(long validationTimeoutMs)
   {
      if (validationTimeoutMs < SOFT_TIMEOUT_FLOOR) {
         throw new IllegalArgumentException("validationTimeout cannot be less than " + SOFT_TIMEOUT_FLOOR + "ms");
      }

      this.validationTimeout = validationTimeoutMs;
   }
```